# Problem with compiling GTK3 program

Tags: 11.10, compiling

I recently decided to learn gtk+, so I installed the gtk3 developement package which contains all the necessary libraries, then I just wrote a simple program test which is supposed to display a gtk window simply and compiles it with the command below :

```
gcc `pkg-config --cflags --libs gtk+-3.0` main.c -o test
```

And the problem is at link time where I'm getting undefined reference to all the functions call :(

```
    /tmp/ccVQOyCZ.o: In function `main':
main.c:(.text+0x1f): undefined reference to `gtk_init'
main.c:(.text+0x29): undefined reference to `gtk_window_new'
main.c:(.text+0x43): undefined reference to `g_type_check_instance_cast'
main.c:(.text+0x64): undefined reference to `g_signal_connect_data'
main.c:(.text+0x70): undefined reference to `gtk_widget_show'
main.c:(.text+0x75): undefined reference to `gtk_main'
/tmp/ccVQOyCZ.o: In function `OnDestroy':
main.c:(.text+0x96): undefined reference to `gtk_main_quit'
collect2: ld returned 1 exit status
```

Voilà, if anyone has a solution...

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Try to reorder gcc options, that is, use:

```
gcc main.c -o test `pkg-config --cflags --libs gtk+-3.0`
```

Comment: Oh many thanks to you dilettant, now it works !

Answer (score 0):

The reorder works for gtk 2.

I installed gtk 2, by advice of a good book "An Introduction to C & GUI Programming by Simon Long", using the next command:

```
sudo apt-get install libgtk2.0-dev
```

but after testing the examples of the book, I get the error that *Pascal Hoareau* commented.

This reorder gcc option worked for me for gtk 2 on Ubuntu 20.04 on raspberry pi 4.

```
gcc main.c -o test `pkg-config --cflags --libs gtk+-2.0`
```

I got some deprecation warnings as these ones https://github.com/FreeSpacenav/spnavcfg/issues/7 but with no errors, my code is working :)

All the examples of the book worked for me on Raspbian OS, but I'm testing Ubuntu mate 20.04, and I think that is a better OS, it is faster and has a nice look. The firefox is working very well, very fast.

In this thread, you can learn why is important the order https://stackoverflow.com/questions/33362579/building-gtk-in-eclipse